# Android Activity Password Protection

Tags: android

Ok, I'm stuck with this problem. I want the "administrator" to be able to add points to a users account. What I want to happen is the administrator has to enter a password to be able to award points to the user. I know that this will have to be in popup format, but I'm just not sure how to do that. So basically my question is: How do I password protect a certain Activity inside of a class?

Comment: If you want them to be able to modify the default password it is going to have to access a server at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality that will this automatically. You can write manual code for a dialog to pop up, accept a password, have an AsyncTask that will verify that password against your server, then add the points or re-route to the desired activity.